# Button positioning in a html form

Tags: html, css, forms, position

Basically i have a form, two inputs for name and password and underneath i have the submit button.

For some reason no matter how i target the submit button i cant change the width of it or figure out how to center it!! Beginning to get very frustrated at this stage as i know its probably only something simple so if anyone can help me out here it would really be appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/DannyW86/3kywX/

Hope this link to the fiddle works

In the fiddle there are 2 buttons because i was trying to see if i could target the buttons different ways but im only going to use one in the end when i can figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just three things inside `#feeder_bm_main input, #feeder_bm_main select`:

```
#feeder_bm_main input, #feeder_bm_main select {
    margin: 5px auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3kywX/1/

Comment: Ah cheers that really helps, but why can i still not alter the width of the individual buttons??

Comment: You can. Why not? What width you need?

Comment: Yes but i only want to change the width of the submit button not the input fields!?

Comment: Okay, in that case, do this... http://jsfiddle.net/3kywX/3/ See the last line in the CSS...

Comment: Ok that kind of worked, i still dont understand why i cant just target the individual button by id and alter the width, height etc? Which CSS rule is preventing em from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `text-align: center` to `.login_container .feeder_bm_login`
2. Remove `float:left` from `#feeder_bm_main input, #feeder_bm_main select`
3. The `width:220px` on `#feeder_bm_main input, #feeder_bm_main select` controls the width of your buttons

Comment: Is there a way i can just target the width of the buttons without changing the with of the input fields???